# How to select distinct values and their occurences from a table in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have a table with the following data example:

| id | first_numbers | second_numbers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 111 | 112 |
| 12 | 111 | 123 |
| 12 | 111 | 122 |
| 12 | 110 | 123 |
| 13 | 100 | null |
| 13 | 100 | 101 |
| 13 | 112 | 999 |
| 13 | null | 999 |

The expected result which I want is the following:

| id | first_numbers | counts | second_numbers | counts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 111 | 3 | 112 | 1 |
| 12 | 110 | 1 | 123 | 2 |
| 12 | null | null | 122 | 1 |
| 13 | 100 | 2 | 101 | 1 |
| 13 | 112 | 1 | 999 | 2 |

Comment: Please [edit] the question to explain the logic of why those values are generated for the output.

Comment: The above table data is a sample but my original data is also the same as above table. Those data are uploaded by an excel file so that I want to determine the occurrences of each number for each id.

Comment: That does not answer the question. What is the reason those numbers are generated for the output? Please explain, in plain English (and not code), how you get from the sample data to the first row of output, or the third row of the output (why is it `null`?).

Comment: Sir as my English is poor so I am so sorry for that. The main data table has many duplicate values as shown in the first table so I want to find out the occurrences for each value based on its related id.

Comment: Why in the third row of the output is there a `NULL` value? There are no `NULL` values for `id = 12` so why should it appear in the output?

Comment: I think id = 12 has three distinct values in second_numbers column but for first_numbers column  there is only two distinct values so therefore third row for id = 12 should be null for column first_numbers. So please show me a solution for that.

Comment: The format of the output doesn't make sense. Putting things on the same row has meaning (**must** have meaning). In your case, you show the distinct values for `first_numbers` and their counts, and also the same for `second_numbers`. There doesn't seem to be any relationship between the values of `first_numbers` and the values of `second_numbers`; so why do you pair them into **rows** in the output? Showing the count for 111 as `first_numbers` side by side with the count for 112 as `second_numbers` is what doesn't make sense. Who or what will need the output *in that format*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not relational. You are treating table values as if they were a flat text file or Excel sheet. I would recommend you review relational concepts and normalization.

Anyway, you can twist SQL's hand to do what you want, but it's not a natural solution. For example, you can do:

```
select
  coalesce(x.id, y.id) as id,
  coalesce(x.r, y.r) as r,
  x.f, x.c,
  y.s, y.c
from (
  select id, f, count(*) as c,
  row_number() over(partition by id order by f) as r from t group by id, f
) x
full join (
  select id, s, count(*) as c,
  row_number() over(partition by id order by s) as r from t group by id, s
) y on y.id = x.id and y.r = x.r
where f is not null or s is not null
order by id, r
```

Result:

```
 ID  R  F    C  S    C 
 --- -- ---- -- ---- - 
 12  1  110  1  112  1 
 12  2  111  3  122  1 
 12  3          123  2 
 13  1  100  2  101  1 
 13  2  112  1  999  2
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=85a8b7d00af109a6b47b4a31ce8563a7).